# Abrir arquivo na memória externa android - Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Na empresa onde trabalho estamos com uma demanda relativamente simples: Quando scanear um QR Code com o tablet da empresa, precisa abrir um .pdf especifico que está na memória do celular. Após tentar meu melhor com a programação em Kotlin, cheguei ao resultado abaixo:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

private var textResult = mutableStateOf("")

private val barCodeLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ScanContract()) {
    result ->
    if(result.contents == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else {
        val pdfUri = Uri.parse(result.contents)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(pdfUri, "application/pdf")
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // ToDo
        }
          textResult.value = result.contents;
    }
}

private fun showCamera(){
    val options = ScanOptions()
    options.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.QR_CODE)
    options.setPrompt("APONTE PARA O QR CODE")
    options.setCameraId(0)
    options.setBeepEnabled(false)
    options.setOrientationLocked(false)

    barCodeLauncher.launch(options)
}

private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
){
    isGranted ->
    if (isGranted){
        showCamera()
    }
}

private val filePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
    if (uri != null) {
        val filePath = uri.toString()
        textResult.value = filePath
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        QRCodeKotlinTheme {
            Scaffold(
                bottomBar = {
                    BottomAppBar(
                        actions = {},
                        floatingActionButton = {
                            Row(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxSize()
                                    .padding(16.dp),
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                            ) {
                                FloatingActionButton(onClick = { checkCameraPermission(this@MainActivity) }) {
                                    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.qr_scan), contentDescription = "QR CODE")
                                }
                                FloatingActionButton(onClick = { openFilePicker() }) {
                                    Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.qr_scan1), contentDescription = "Open File Picker")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            ) { InnerPadding ->
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(InnerPadding),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ){
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.qr_scan),
                            modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp),
                            contentDescription = "QR"
                        )
                        ClickableText(
                            text = AnnotatedString(textResult.value),
                            onClick = { offset ->
                                selectText(offset, textResult.value.length)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private fun selectText(start: Int, end: Int) {
    val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    val selectedText = textResult.value.substring(start, end)
    val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", selectedText)
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun openFilePicker() {
    filePickerLauncher.launch("*/*")
}

private fun checkCameraPermission(context: Context) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        showCamera()
    }
    else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Camera Requirida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else{
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
}
```

}

Basicamente tem dois botões: O "openFilePicker" permite navegar na memória do tablet e selecionar um arquivo, retornando na tela um texto que pode ser copiado. Já o "barCodeLauncher" é responsável por abrir o arquivo após fazer a leitura do QRCode.

O app funciona quando faço os testes, porém por algum motivo bizarro ele só funciona quando eu utilizo a função "openFilePicker" e seleciono algum arquivo pdf, se eu não fazer isso, eu scaneio os QRCode com o diretório do arquivo e nada acontece, basta selecionar qualquer arquivo .pdf no tablet e quando eu scaneio os QRCode com um diretório o arquivo abre normalmente.

Alguma ideia do que pode estar causando isso?